# Is it possible to change the PostgreSQL hostname from localhost to IP address?

Tags: postgresql

Sorry for the very elementary question.

I created a simple web app that connects with a database for learning.
PostgreSQL is using 13.

Right now, I'm running both the database and the application on my local PC, but I wanted to see if I could view this application from another PC.

The application will be created in C# and Blazor, and the connection to the database will be made using NpgSQL.

We can connect the application and database with localhost within the local PC, but we cannot connect with localhost from other PCs, so we want to change the host of PostgreSQL to an IP address.

I'm thinking of connecting a local PC (say A) and another PC (say B).

Connect the Lan cable directly to both PCs and place them under the same network.

Set the IP address temporarily as follows.

A is 192.168.1.1
B is 192.168.1.10

In this case, if I set the database connection string in the application to 192.168.1.1, am I correct in understanding that I can reference the database from both PC(A) and PC(B)?
Sorry I don't have the environment to verify this right now.

Comment: Ask somebody who knows a little bit about networks. This is not a programming question.

Comment: Since you didn't show how you connect in the first place, how can we tell you what to change?  I would guess that where you currently say "localhost", change it to say "192.168.1.10"

Comment: I have reviewed my question.
I apologize for the lack of information.

Comment: Connecting by IP address is fine. Just be aware that the PostgreSQL server can have different rules for allowing connections for users coming in from outside the machine. You may have to edit [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) on the server.  `localhost` is a special network address for the machine itself. It's like "me". There is also a special address 127.0.0.1 which is also the machine itself or "me".